# understanding parts of this Sudoku solver

Tags: java, recursion, solver, sudoku

I have a question about the following code snippet.  This is from a sudoku solver I found on youtube.  It uses a recursive backtracking algorithm to solve.  I'm just trying to learn from this, but I'm stuck on some parts.
The following snippet is a boolean to check if a number is in a 3x3 box, this is used later in the solve() method.

```
// we check if a possible number is in its 3x3 box
private boolean isInBox(int row, int col, int number) {
    int r = row - row % 3;
    int c = col - col % 3;

    for (int i = r; i < r + 3; i++)
        for (int j = c; j < c + 3; j++)
            if (board[i][j] == number)
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

I just don't understand how this works.  What does row - row % 3 do?  And then in the for loop i < r + 3 confuses me too.  I understand the rows and column checkers, those are easy, but the logic here is escaping me.

Comment: If you plug in some sample inputs for the args row and col, what do those first 2 lines do? Try values 1 to 3 (within 3x3) and then > 3 (outside 3x3) and what do you notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` and `col` can be any value from 0 to 8. They define a location within the 9x9 sudoku game.

The loops need to check the specific 3x3 box that the location `row,col` is contained within.

`int r = row - row % 3;` finds the index of the first row in that same 3x3 box.

`int c = col - col % 3;` finds the index of the first column in that same 3x3 box.

Both convert the input value to output as:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
3 -> 3
4 -> 3
5 -> 3
6 -> 6
7 -> 6
8 -> 6
```

The loop then checks every location from `r,c` up to `r+2,c+2` (inclusive), looking for the specified value `number`.